# La parola "bovazza" è un termine di uso regionale?

Tags: word-usage, regional

Nel romanzo *Pane e tempesta* di Stefano Benni ho letto questa frase:

> Alice amava la natura in tutte le sue forme, dalla più umile **bovazza** di mucca al più raffinato disegno sulle ali di una farfalla.

Non ho trovato il vocabolo "bovazza" in nessuno dei dizionari online che consulto di solito. Tuttavia, appare in questo [Vocabolario italiano-ferrarese](http://www.ferraraforum.it/index.php?act=attach&type=post&id=22021) e il suo significato sembra essere "escremento bovino". Secondo questo documento, però,  si tratta di un termine italianizzato, il termine in ferrarese è "buàzza". La mia domanda è: "bovazza" è un vocabolo di uso regionale? In quali regioni d'Italia si usa?

Comment: La parola ha diverse varianti regionali in quanto era molto comune data la tradizione agricola dell'Italia. In Veneto ad esempio è "boassa", ma ci sono varianti a seconda della zona anche all'interno delle stesse regioni.

Comment: Bovazza sembra essere il termine "sdoganato" dalla lingua italiana per riferirsi alle molte varianti regionali .

Comment: Sono d'accordo con te, bovazza tenta di ricondurre le numerose varianti ad un termine simil-italiano

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il termine viene utilizzato a livello regionale e ha diverse varianti.

Nella zona di Bologna per esempio esiste il termine ***[boazza](https://bolognabloguniversity.it/guida-allo-slang-bolognese-bl-bol/)***

> boa(z)za /a/ s. m. 1 sensazione di grande stanchezza; “ho una gran
>   boazza addosso” 2 ***grosso escremento di vacca, ma più in generale di
>   qualsiasi animale; “ho pestato una boazza!”***. Per 1 vedi anche fiacca,
>   flemma, stufisia.

un termine colloquiale che indica (anche) l'escremento di vacca.

In Trentino si fa riferimento sempre alla ***[boaza](http://ricerca.gelocal.it/trentinocorrierealpi/archivio/trentinocorrierealpi/2010/04/01/AV3PO_AV302.html)*** con lo stesso significato.

In Veneto, come giustamente fa notare @Gio, viene usata la variante ***[boassa](https://it.glosbe.com/vec/it/boassa)***.

In questo [dizionario dialettale](http://www.dialettando.com/dizionario/detail.lasso?id=4520) puoi trovare ulteriori varianti:

> Canton Ticino sterco bovino, vaccina: ***buascia***
>
> Emilia Romagna sterco bovino: ***buàsa***
>
> Friuli Venezia Giulia sterco bovino: ***boassa***
>
> Lombardia sterco bovino, vaccina: ***bovàscia*** (Milano), ***sciòta***, ***sciòta***
>   (Valtellina/SO)
>
> Veneto sterco bovino: ***boassa***

Comment: Forse val la pena di menzionare che Benni è bolognese e quindi la *boazza*, giustamente menzionata per prima, è forse quella che ha più in mente quando scrive.

Comment: Concordo. "Boazza" è evidentemente il termine che è stato italianizzato in "bovazza", con la semplice aggiunta di una "V" tra le due vocali: -oa- > -ova-.

Comment: Bassa Lombardia, nel triangolo delle quattro province: buàsa....mi ha aperto il cuore, leggere questo termine, mi ha riportato alla mia infanzia tra i contadini ❤